# How can I connect dishwasher waste pipe to sink waste pipe?

Tags: sink, drain-waste-vent, dishwasher

I moved in recently in our new home and when we put the dishwasher on a gush of water appeared on the floor.  I turned off the dishwasher and took a look under the sink to find the waste pipe was loose on the floor.

The first image shows the damage when it first happened.  You can see the pipe at the back and its clearly not connected to anything.  Have no idea why they left it like this and not told us atleast.

[image: Dishwasher water spill]

The Second image shows the dishwasher pipe once I pulled it out.
[image: Dishwasher Waste Pipe]

This third image shows how the washing machine is connected at the moment to the sink waste outlets.  Clearly there is no room here for a dishwasher waste pipe..

[image: How its all connected just now]

So my questions are:

- How can I connect the dishwasher waste to this setup?  Its made more complicated because we have two sinks and I can't find the connector that would allow for two waste connectors to be attached (for the dishwasher and washing machine) and for the two sinks.  I have no idea what this would be called and how it could be installed so if anyone can guide me that would be great!
- Why wold they leave the pipe?  Is it maybe broken off from an attachment behind the washing machine?? The washing machine is integrated so its a real pain pulling it out to check behind it.  Is it possible that this pipe was connect to the washing machine waste pipe instead of it being connected directly to the sink?
- I am new to this but willing to follow instructions :)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the black pipe connected to the sink basket (top of the third photo)? Is it possible that the previous resident swapped the dishwasher and laundry waste pipe, depending on what they were using?

Comment: @Tester101 "Is it possible that the previous resident swapped the dishwasher and laundry waste pipe", that was my exact thought when I got to the third picture, the diameter of the washing machine hose and dishwasher are the same.